# Java SWT StyledText, changing the starting line number

Tags: java, swt, styledtext

I am currently using a `StyledText` widget to display some "excerpt" of the actual code, such as a method definition within a Java file.

My problem is that the line number shown in my `StyledText` always start with 1, which is different from the actual line number in the original file. For example, if the original source looks like:

```
1:  package something;
2:  
3:  public class MyClass {
4:      public void foo() {
5:          // Do something...
6:      }
7:  }
```

then, when the `foo()` method is shown in my `StyledText` widget, I want to show the line numbers starting from 4, not 1.

Is there a way to achieve this? I read through the javadoc, but could not figure out a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `LineStyleEvent.bulletIndex` in the `LineStyleListener`:

```
final StyledText text = new StyledText(shell, SWT.NONE);

text.setText("lalala\n\nlalala\n\nlalala\n\nlalala\n\nlalala\n\nlalala\n\n");
text.addLineStyleListener(new LineStyleListener()
{
    @Override
    public void lineGetStyle(LineStyleEvent e)
    {
        // Set the line number
        e.bulletIndex = text.getLineAtOffset(e.lineOffset);

        // Set the style, 12 pixles wide for each digit
        StyleRange style = new StyleRange();
        style.metrics = new GlyphMetrics(0, 0, Integer.toString(text.getLineCount() + 1).length() * 12);

        // Create and set the bullet
        e.bullet = new Bullet(ST.BULLET_NUMBER, style);

        // Apply the offset
        e.bulletIndex += YOUR_OFFSET; // I used 3 here
    }
});
```

Looks like this:

[image]